# code snippets in styling django template bootstrap

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I have to include variables while styling django templates using Bootstrap.

`<div class="card mb-2 text-white bg-info">`

The info part will be changed for each card accordingly.
Is there any way similair to this ?

`<div class="card mb-2 text-white bg-{card.category}">`

`card` is from the respective model.

Please help

Comment: Not sure what you're asking - you seem to have the answer (though vars need `{{` rather than `{ ` in django templates).

Answer (score 0):

Putting a condition can be helpful:

```
<div class="card mb-2 text-white bg-
    {% if card.category==value1 %} class A 
    {% elif card.category==value2 %} class B
    {% else %} class C
    {% endif %}
">
```